# how to alignment the output of the last fields

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, printf

the bash script

```
for i in $script_name
do
  echo -en "running the script - $i\t - "
  exec 3>&1 4>&2
  var=$( { time /tmp/scripts/$i 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1)  # Captures time only
  exec 3>&- 4>&-

  echo "$var"
done
```

print the following:

```
running the script - Verify_disk.bash -       1.42
running the script - Verify_yum_list.bash - 10.49
running the script - Verify_size.bash -   2.93
running the script - Verify_mem_size.bash -       0.71
running the script - Verify_disk_size.bash -      2.41
running the script - Verify_wdisk.bash -        1.63
running the script - Verify_cpu.bash - 0.74
```

since $var is the variable that print all these output
we want to alignment the output

so it will be like this

```
running the script - Verify_disk.bash        -   1.42
running the script - Verify_yum_list.bash    -   10.49
running the script - Verify_size.bash        -   2.93
running the script - Verify_mem_size.bash    -   0.71
running the script - Verify_disk_size.bash   -   2.41
running the script - Verify_wdisk.bash       -   1.63
running the script - Verify_cpu.bash         -   0.74
```

what are the additional changes that should be with $var in order to  alignment the last fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a pre-loop to calculate the longest filename then use that as a spacing parameter:

```
longest=0
for file in *.bash
do
  [ "${#file}" -gt "$longest" ] && longest=${#file}
done

# ... for your execution loop
printf "running the script - %${longest}s\t- "
printf "%s\n" "$var"
```

I assume that all of your scripts are covered by the wildcard `*.bash`; adjust that as needed. The initial loops calculates the needed width; the initial `printf` uses that variable to format the width of the script field for every iteration of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do the formatting proper inside the script as the earlier iterations of the loop have no way of knowing the width of the following variables; how about a two-step process?

I also took the liberty (personal preference) to right-align the output of the time values.

Having saved your example input to file (can't generate that dynamically) my suggestion looks like this:

```
cat yael | awk -F'-' '{printf "%s - %-30s - % 6.2f\n",$1, $2, $3}' 
running the script  -  Verify_disk.bash              -   1.42
running the script  -  Verify_yum_list.bash          -  10.49
running the script  -  Verify_size.bash              -   2.93
running the script  -  Verify_mem_size.bash          -   0.71
running the script  -  Verify_disk_size.bash         -   2.41
running the script  -  Verify_wdisk.bash             -   1.63
running the script  -  Verify_cpu.bash               -   0.74
```

So if you were to pipe the output of your script through my awk ...